# Desktop keyboard behaves as on a Notebook

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-layout, windows-media-center, hid

On a Desktop PC running Windows 7 Ultimate (64-bit), I have recently installed a Microsoft CIR receiver (designed for WinXP MCE). Whilst the receiver works as expected with both WMC remote and keyboard, the main USB full-size keyboard now behaves like a notebook PC.

Specifically this results in some of the letter keys sending numbers when NumLock is switched on. Whilst turning NumLock off allows the letters to be used, it also disables the Number Pad (as expected).

How can I restore the keyboard to its proper functionality?

PS. I'm using the default HID drivers from Windows Update for the keyboard